# how do I replace all string including square bracket in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I would like to replace all `animal[0]` to `animal[1]` in html.
but I don't want to replace `tiger[0]` to `tiger[1]` in the same html.

for example,

```
<input type="hidden" name="animal[0].tiger[0].prey"/>
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" name="animal[1].tiger[0].prey"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? It doesn't seem like you even need regex to do this, unless there is more to it you didn't mention...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these

1. Use attribute selector **[`[name^="animal[0]"]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** , which will select tags that have name attribute having value `animal[0]` at beginning([`^` is for represent at the start](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)).
2. **[`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)** method to iterate through each input tag with name starting with `animal[0]`.
3. Use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** for replacing `animal[0]` to `animal[1]`.

```
$('input[name^="animal[0]"]').each(function(){
    this.name=this.name.replace('animal[0]', 'animal[1]')
});
```

Comment: "Try this" doesn't explain the code ;)

Comment: I don't know how to thank your quick answer. you're very helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = htmlString.replace('animal[0', 'animal[1');
```

Comment: Please explain all answers you post. What if the OP doesn't know how to grab the input element to run a replace on it?

Comment: @RUJordan IOW what this answer does is only a small part of what needs to be done and we don't know how much of it the asker _can_ do by himself.

Comment: @JanDvorak absolutely right

Comment: @RUJordan, all the OP said was to replace. Easy as that so what's the issue?

Comment: @hwnd it doesn't matter if it's a one line answer or a novel of an answer. All good answers are explained. Even if it's just a few words. It makes that difference.

Comment: I appeciate you too. you exactly know where I have a trouble. thanks.